# How to delete one file at a time sequentially?

Tags: shell, unix

I have multiple files in a dir as below

```
Movie22017-06-14_12:18:01.tmp.mp4
Movie22017-06-14_12:18:40.tmp.mp4
Movie22017-06-14_12:19:19.tmp.mp4
Movie22017-06-14_12:19:58.tmp.mp4
Movie22017-06-14_12:20:37.tmp.mp4
```

**Question** I want to delete these files but not all at once. I want to first delete "Movie22017-06-14_12:18:01.tmp.mp4" than 5 seconds later delete "Movie22017-06-14_12:18:40.tmp.mp4" and so on. How can I achieve this? Basically first in first out.

Comment: Where are the filenames? In a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through all files in a directory, and then run some code on that, such as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/files/here/*
for f in $FILES; do
  echo "Deleting '$f'..."
  rm -f "$f"
  sleep 5
done
```

Note: this will break if there are any spaces in the file path

Comment: This breaks if the path in  `FILES` contains a space or newline character.

Comment: To avoid the problem, `find /path/to/files -type f | sort | { while read -r f; do rm -f $f; sleep 5; done; }` (it's up to you to define the sort order if other than alphabetical)

Comment: Or just `for f in '/path/with space/here/'*`, or `mypath='/path/with space'; for f in "$mypath"/*; do`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin How does that avoid the problem? Wouldn't you have to use `-print0` and `sort -z` and `read -d ''`?

Comment: Because `find` output is one filename per-line which `read -r f` will read regardless of spaces. Now, one issue remains. That is filenames with embedded newlines (legal, but rare). That's what your `-print0` will protect against. (personally, I think anybody that would embed newlines in a filename should be shot in the head, but... to each his own `:)`